# How to Check the duplicate in application state in mvc asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how to check the duplicate in Application state

My problem scenario:

I stored the username and password in the application[""] variable.
another user enters the username password i want to check for each and every user.

i tried for for loop but hard to find the count..

could you help me check the duplicate

```
     for (int j = 0; j < (int)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application["Userlogin"].ToString().Length - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application[i].ToString() == sKey)
                    {
                        Session["duplicateuser"] = "logout";
                        Returnmsg = "-3";
                    }
                }
```

but it shows the string length of the application[]

Thank in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I stored the username and password in the application[""] variable

Wow, don't. The Application state is shared among all users of your application. Never store user specific data in application state. Use Session state instead.

---

UPDATE:

If you want to check for concurrent user access you could store a collection of users into the application state such as `IEnumerable<string>`. Then you could check if a user is already logged in easily:

```
public bool IsUserLoggedIn(string username, HttpApplicationStateBase application)
{
    var users = application["users"] as IEnumerable<string>;
    if (users == null)
    {
        users = new ConcurrentBag<string>();
        application["users"] = users;
    }

    return users.Any(u => u == username);
}
```

Comment: i trying to do for concurrent user login check, for that im trying to store username only if the user is already their, i used to logout two users

Comment: In this case you should store a collection of users into the application state. I have updated my answer to provide an example.

Comment: thank you very much for your response.   could you explain elaborately, do you mean that instead of Application i have to use IList<string> or have to user IList in Application[]state, if so explain it please...